# Does single webpage do not need navigation to create a slug in permalink?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, navigation, slug

I have concern about the permalink in my working project do i need to create a slug for the permalink in navigation. Your answer will highly appreciated.

Someone help me stock in

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry: you have a single page and you want to link to that page from the menu? Pages will automatically have slugs generated from their page title, and you can use the URL with the slug in your menu, yes.

Comment: But you've tagged this theme development. Are you writing a theme that assumes a page with a specific slug is present in the site? I'm still a bit confused sorry.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out @Rup